# Tensorflow Keras TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.layers as nn
import numpy as np

class Base(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Base, self).__init__()
        
        self.user_emb = nn.Embedding(20000, 128, input_length=1)
        self.item_emb = nn.Embedding(10000, 128, input_length=1)

        self.test_dense = nn.Dense(80, activation=None)
        self.final_dense = nn.Dense(1)

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        user, item = inputs
        user_emb = self.user_emb(user)
        item_emb = self.item_emb(item)

        join_emb = tf.concat([user_emb, item_emb], -1)

        logit = self.test_dense(join_emb)
        logit = tf.squeeze(self.final_dense(logit))
        output = tf.nn.sigmoid(logit)

        return output

# Main
if __name__ == '__main__':

    model = Base()
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=[])

    a = np.random.randint(1,20000,size=(10000))
    b = np.random.randint(1, 10000, size=(10000))
    y = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(10000))
    X = [a, b]
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=32)
```

When I run the above code, I get

> TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len().

I use Tensorflow 2.0.0, python 3.6

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded my Tensorflow version to `2.0.0` and ran the your code which produced the same error.

When I upgraded to version `2.4.1` it works perfectly fine.

You can upgrade Tensorflow like this:

```
pip install tensorflow==2.4.1
```

Comment: Thank you! I found the solution. When I remove tf.squeeze() of last layer, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to remove tf.squeeze() of last layer.